# Why do Figures not show up?

Tags: floats

I am using one of Overleaf's templates, which is designed to put figures on the last page with a description in the text. I removed the floating package in order to show figures in the text, but after that, the figures are not showing up anymore.
Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\makeatletter\if@twocolumn\PassOptionsToPackage{switch}{lineno}\else\fi\makeatother
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy,latexsym,tabulary,times,xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url,multirow,cancel,tfrupee,multicol}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{float}
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{textcomp}{}{\usepackage{textcomp}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}
\urlstyle{rm}
\makeatletter

%Etal definition in references
\@ifundefined{etal}{\def\etal{\textit{et~al}}}{}

\AtBeginDocument{
\expandafter\ifx\csname eqalign\endcsname\relax
\def\eqalign#1{\null\vcenter{\def\\{\cr}\openup\jot\m@th
  \ialign{\strut$\displaystyle{##}$\hfil&$\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil
      \crcr#1\crcr}}\,}
\fi
}

\@ifundefined{tsGraphicsScaleX}{\gdef\tsGraphicsScaleX{1}}{}
\@ifundefined{tsGraphicsScaleY}{\gdef\tsGraphicsScaleY{.9}}{}
% To automatically resize figures to fit inside the text area
\def\checkGraphicsWidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \tsGraphicsScaleX\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}

\def\checkGraphicsHeight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>.9\textheight
    \tsGraphicsScaleY\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}

\def\fixFloatSize#1{}%\@ifundefined{processdelayedfloats}{\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}}\ifnum\wd0<\columnwidth\relax\renewenvironment{figure*}{\begin{figure}}{\end{figure}}\fi}{}}
\let\ts@includegraphics\includegraphics

\def\inlinegraphic[#1]#2{{\edef\@tempa{#1}\edef\baseline@shift{\ifx\@tempa\@empty0\else#1\fi}\edef\tempZ{\the\numexpr(\numexpr(\baseline@shift*\f@size/100))}\protect\raisebox{\tempZ pt}{\ts@includegraphics{#2}}}}

%\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\ts@includegraphics[width=\checkGraphicsWidth]{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\includegraphics{\@ifnextchar[{\ts@includegraphics}{\ts@includegraphics[width=\checkGraphicsWidth,height=\checkGraphicsHeight,keepaspectratio]}}}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\def\URL#1#2{\@ifundefined{href}{#2}{\href{#1}{#2}}}

\edef\fntEncoding{\f@encoding}
\def\EUoneEnc{EU1}
\makeatother
\def\floatpagefraction{0.8} 
\def\dblfloatpagefraction{0.8}
\def\style#1#2{#2}
\def\xxxguillemotleft{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\guillemotleft}
\def\xxxguillemotright{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\guillemotright}

\newif\ifmultipleabstract\multipleabstractfalse%
\newenvironment{typesetAbstractGroup}{}{}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[hmargin=1.8cm,vmargin=2.2cm]{geometry}%,headsep=0.3in,footskip=0.49in
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.25in}
\setlength\headheight{19.5pt}

\makeatletter
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{\hskip-\dimexpr(\tabcolsep)\hskip1pt\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-1pt}{\centering #1}}}

\let\@articletype\@empty \def\articletype#1{\gdef\@articletype{{\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont #1}}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{headings}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[RE]{\MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\RunningAuthor}}}\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage}}\fancyhead[LO]{\MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\RunningHead}}}\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}}\pagestyle{headings}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}}}

\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{lastpage}}
\def\title#1{%
  \gdef\@title{%
%   {\vspace*{-42pt}\raggedright\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\textbf{\MakeTextUppercase{\journalTitle}}\\%
%   \textbf{Volume xx, Number x, \the\year}\\%
%   \textbf{Mary Ann Liebert, Inc.}\\%
%   \textbf{Pp. 1--\pageref{LastPage}}\\%
%   \textbf{DOI: 10.1089/xxx.xxxx.xxxx}\\}%
    \ifx\@articletype\@empty\else\@articletype~\\\fi%
     #1}%
}


\usepackage{abstract}
\def\abstractname{\textbf{Abstract}}
\renewenvironment{onecolabstract}
{\vspace*{-.4pc}\trivlist\item[]\leftskip1pt\noindent\selectfont\hfill\abstractname\hfill\mbox{\null}\par\ignorespaces}{\endtrivlist}

\def\NormalBaseline{\def\baselinestretch{1.1}}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\NormalBaseline\boldmath\bfseries}
{\thesection.}
{6pt}
{#1}
[]
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\NormalBaseline\filright\itshape}
{\thesubsection.}
{6pt}
{#1}
[]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\NormalBaseline\filright\itshape}
{\hspace{16pt}\thesubsubsection}
{6pt}
{#1}
[]
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\NormalBaseline}
{\theparagraph}
{6pt}
{#1}
[]
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\NormalBaseline}
{\thesubparagraph}
{6pt}
{#1}
[]

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{.2\baselineskip}  
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{.2\baselineskip}  
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{.2\baselineskip}  
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{.5\baselineskip}{10pt}  
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0pt}{.5\baselineskip}{10pt}


\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{figlabel}{Figure #2}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={footnotesize},labelfont={bf},labelformat=figlabel,skip=1.4pt,aboveskip=1pc,labelsep=period,justification=centering}
\captionsetup[table]{font={footnotesize},skip=1.4pt,labelsep=period,justification=centering}

\date{}
\makeatother


% \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Document content starts below
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\title{Causality Principle and the Road Toward Universal Theory}
\def\RunningHead{
Preparation of papers short title
}
\def\RunningAuthor{Albustanji}
\author{Abd Almonaem Albustanji}
\maketitle


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

{\begin{onecolabstract}
Here the abstract

%%\def\keywordstitle{Keywords}
%%\smallskip\noindent\textbf{Keywords: }{\normalfont
%%Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3}
\end{onecolabstract}}
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{Introduction}
The geometrical structure of the special theory of relativity was formulated by Minkowski after the Einsteinian physical interpretation of Lorentz transformations rather than the Lorentzian interpretation, which is an abstract mathematical necessity, and it is actually a necessity to guarantee the invariance or at least the covariance of the laws of physics in Newtonian frames of reference, this principle is usually called \textit{the Galilean invariance\;/\; covariance principle}. Einstein's idea was centered on considering parameters $(t,t')$ in Lorentz transformations as a time parameter each for two different inertial observers, which was done by embracing the idea of relative time. He supported his assumptions using Maxwellian theory in electromagnetism, and by considering his claim, he destroyed one of the basic principles in classical mechanics, which is \textit{the absoluteness of time}. Einstein by his assumptions redefined the classical picture of space and time, which can be seen by considering the following gedankenexperiment.
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{1.png}
  \label{Einstein's gedankenexperiment.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the result
[image]

any help?

Comment: You posted an unreasonable amount of code but the warning from latex surely explains the issue: `Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside \`multicols' 
environment!.`

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience; I'm not an expert in coding and defining packages. How can I allow figures in multicols? or what I should do?

Comment: Because `figure` without `\caption` does not make sense, you could, e.g., use a `center` environment instead of a `figure`. BTW: `\label` without `\caption` also does not make sense. As an alternative use LaTeX's native twocolumn mode (e.g. with class option `twocolumn` or command `\twocolumn`).

Comment: @cabohah Thanks, it works, but I need the abstract section and the footnote to be out of the columns. How can I pull them out?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).